# Play a video on Android using a videoview container

Tags: android, video

Im trying to understand how to add video to my application using the VideoView container but so far I've never been able to view a video and all i receive is an error 'Can't play this video'.

I have a simple method that load's the video:-

```
    private void setupVideo() {

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath("video/Test_Movie.m4v");
    videoView.start();

    }
```

I have tried converting the video to many H264, H263 , 3gp formats but I can find anything that works.I even have downloaded a video that said worked in a book i have but still doesn't work.

any help appreciated!

thx.

Comment: try to use try-catch and see if theres any exception

Comment: HI, just tried that...nothing I'm afraid. The only error that i do get is (even before try/catch) is 'error (1, -2147483648)'. But that doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: oh no...sorry cant help you..just upvoted your question, hope someone will come :)

Comment: are you trying to play the video in an emulator?

Comment: HI I've tried playing it in the emulator and on a physical HTC one on 4.4.2, both give the same result(error).

Comment: I think the issue is in line  videoView.setVideoPath("video/Test_Movie.m4v");

Comment: Hi , The issue is in the path you are setting to play the video. If you try to change the line videoView.setVideoPath("video/Test_Movie.m4v") with some online video url, It plays the video perfectly. So the issue is in path given

Comment: Can you please tell me where Test_Movie.m4v video file is located?.. I can help you get the solution If I get to know the location.

Comment: Hi, the movie file is located in the res/video folder (I manually created the video folder myself).

Comment: HI All, it looks like the issue is down to my misunderstanding of how you are supposed to deliver resources for use by an android application. I have opened up DDMS (and wrote some code to list the files in the folder I am targeting) and found that there is no video file present. Maybe my question should really be - How do I deliver a video file with my app so that I can play it from within?